# Auromatically Launching Firefox To Run An HTML File

Tags: firefox, games, steam

My son has developed a game in HTML that he wants to put on Steam.  For Windows he has a batch file to open the browser, then run the HTML to launch the game.

He wants to do the same for Linux, but he's brand new to the OS and it's beyond my ability (I can only manage the basics in Linux).

How could he go about doing this?  Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried any documentation on creating bash scripts?  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Beginners/BashScripting etc

Comment: from CLI on my Ubuntu system, I can use `firefox https://askubuntu.com` to cause `firefox` to open a new tab (*it's already open on my box, or start browser*) & open it to `https://askubuntu.com` or this website; but that could be a local file if that is what is specified). I'm assuming a Ubuntu Desktop system here as you weren't specific, and this is a Ubuntu specific site.

Comment: Try `man firefox`. `firefox -help`, `firefox http://localhost/`

Comment: The preferred way may be to use `xdg-open /path/to/htmlfile`  respectively `xdg-open URL` to open the system's standard browser and open the HTML file (or URL). This will work on all Linux distros following the XDG spec (which is the vast majority of Linux distros)
Calling Firefox explicitly may _not_ be a good idea, as many users may not use Firefox, but other browsers. Remember that the market share of Firefox is small compared to Chrome / Chromium, Edge and Safari is very small, thus relying on having the Firefox available may be a mistake.